# Can the filesystem of an Android device be accessed directly from an application?

Tags: android, filesystems

Can the filesystem of an Android device be accessed directly by an application? In Windows an application can directly access the Windows filesystem. But in iOS applications can't access the filesystem of iOS directly. So please help me: what exactly happens for android?

Comment: I use the Astro app to do that :D It uses linux paths to address files

Answer (score 2):

You can access android file system from Java's [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) API, by directly specifying paths (unix style):

```
File f = new File("/data/data/com.example.app/cache/sample.txt");
```

Note that not all paths are accessible due to different access permissions.

Also, android API provides access to many frequently accessed files and file operations directly. Have a look at [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) class, it provides many such methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes file system can be accessed from the app. File APIs allow you to do that.

developer.android.com links explaining the saving of file and storage options and making files which are not accessible by other applications:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html